# Google Kubernetes Engine network is not working properly

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, gke-networking

I'm using GKE and I have two deployments, one service and one postgres instance. I was debugging -since I am really new on it- and suddenly I could not access my service from outside from its IP. Neither the connections from my deployments to my sql instances works now. I tried a lot of things (creating a new cluster, creating new database, changing static ips and so on).

I found this help page: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-service, but when I tried to run `nslookup hostnames` I found this:

```
bash: nslookup: command not found
```

I tried to install it but

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package nslookup
```

I'm not sure if the issue is related to firewall or DNS. It is strange that I could not debug in the way documentation suggests.

Edit: I am using 1.10.11-gke.1

Comment: `nslookup` is provided by [`dnsutils` in ubuntu bionic](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=nslookup&mode=exactfilename&suite=bionic&arch=any) and the [same in debian](https://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=contents&keywords=nslookup&mode=path&suite=stable&arch=amd64). You may be happier with `dig`, also from that same `dnsutils` package, as it can be easier to make complicated queries. In a pinch, even using `curl -v` will serve as a DNS query since `curl` emits the IP when connecting to it

Comment: It was working before and randomly stopped working?

Comment: What version of GKE are you using?

Comment: @Rico: Yes, It was working before.

Comment: @MatthewLDaniel I tried dig but it didn't work either.

Comment: @MuhammadEbaduddin I edited the original question with GKE version.

Comment: Container OS or the Ubuntu image for GKE do not include any additional packages, nor can you install any. Your best bet is to SSH to a node then run "sudo toolbox bash" which will create a container that allows you to install the debugging tools.

Comment: Can you also provide more details about your setup and the workflow. Is everything contained within GKE or are pods connecting to an external postgres SQL instance?